# keyboard TAB selection is not visible

Tags: html, css, focus, angular6, primeng

I have an angular application, when I use keyboard TAB to move around the elements, current focused element is not highlighting.

This is how it looks like when I TAB to an element

[image]

This is when I then click on space to expand the accordionTab
[image]

I then added the following CSS but it's working only on mouse hover BUT not on tab selection.

```
::ng-deep {
    .ui-accordion-header:hover, .ui-accordion-header:active, .ui-accordion-header:focus {
        border: solid #00a1cf 1px !important;
    }
}
```

[image]

I had been testing, it is working when I force select **focus** in chrome developer tools but not when I keyboard tab select.

[image]

I am unable to figure out why its not highlighting when **focus**ed using keyboard TAB. Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you using a third party library like angular material for your accordion?  If so, you may want to check their documentation for intercepting keyboard events and focusing on their elements.  Good general discussions about this on [MDN-Widgets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/Keyboard-navigable_JavaScript_widgets), and [MDN-Focus and Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Tutorial/Focus_and_Selection)

Answer (score 1):

What does the markup look like? Normally when tabbing to focus the elements that have focus by default are:

- **a (anchors)**
- **buttons**
- **inputs**
- **textareas**

If you have a different type of element such as a div, you can try and give it focus by adding **tabindex** to your markup.